# How can I spawn processes without fork() in Python 2.7?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, multiprocessing, fork, python-multiprocessing

Python 3.4+ added `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` which allows to create processes that don't share memory with the main process. I'm trying to get this behavior in Python 2.7. Are there any backports of the `multiprocessing.Process` class, alternative multiprocessing packages, or lower-level functions I can use?

Update: Regarding the close vote, I'd like to clarify that I'm not asking for subjective software recommendations. Instead, I'm trying to find any solution to this problem that works, and after browsing the web for a while, it seems like a manual solution using low-level functions might be necessary.

Comment: could you post an update on this research, I also need such a thing in 2.7

Comment: @d-d I wish but I haven't found a solution.

Comment: Also interested in this, I may just have to move to Python 3.4+.

Comment: I'm glad Python 2 is dead now.

Comment: Have you been able to create a work-around to using the SPAWN method? I have same issue and wish to hear from your solution. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `os.fork()` for your.use case? What about `subprocess.Popen()`?